# jQuery unique, diferença no Chrome e Firefox?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, firefox

Estou tendo um comportamento inesperado com o `unique`do jQuery.

O seguinte comando:

```
 var x = [1,2,1,2];
 var y = $.unique(x);
 document.write(y);
```

No Chrome tem como resultado `1,2` (o que está correto), mas no Firefox aparece `1,2,1,2`.

Isto é um bug, ou era para ser assim mesmo?

Segue exemplo no [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/d7TRB/1/), abra primeiro no Chrome (funciona corretamente) e depois no Firefox (não funciona).

***OBS***: *jQuery 2.1.0; Firefox 24.5.0; Google Chrome 34.0.1847.131 m.*

Comment: Encontrei na página de bugs de jQuery o seguinte: `$.unique() is only designed to work on DOM nodes, not on arrays of strings.` http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/7036

Comment: @Sergio olha só, o bug tá fechado como inválido > "closed bug: invalid"

Comment: @guisantogui O bug é inválido justamente porque a função está sendo usada de forma diferente do que foi projetada.

Comment: Uma sugestão: para obter elementos únicos de um Array, converta-o para um objeto. Todo objeto em Javascript é praticamente um dicionário, assim você pode garantir a unicidade ;) Exemplo com todos os valores como `true`: `var z = {"1": true, "2": true};`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

O `.unique()`do jQuery não foi desenhado para numeros ou strings. Na documentação do jQuery pode ler-se:

> Sorts an array of DOM elements, in place, with the duplicates removed. Note that this only works on arrays of DOM elements, not strings or numbers.

na nossa língua sería:

> Ordena uma array de elementos DOM, removendo os duplicados. Note que isto só funciona em elementos DOM e não numeros ou strings.

Aqui fica código em javascript para fazer o que precisa: http://jsfiddle.net/4SBVQ/

```
var arrayUnique = function(a) {
    return a.reduce(function(p, c) {
        if (p.indexOf(c) < 0) p.push(c);
        return p;
    }, []);
};
```

Fonte: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4833835/2256325